# Installing 'gcloud' inside Go Docker image, cannot find Python

Tags: gcloud, bitbucket-pipelines, google-cloud-sdk

I have a Bitbucket pipeline based on a Go 1.19 Docker image. The pipeline installs *gcloud*.

```
- curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com > /tmp/gcl && bash /tmp/gcl --install-dir=~/gcloud --disable-prompts
```

Until this afternoon, it worked fine, but it now started failing with:

> /root/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh: 224: python: not found

I see that 'gcloud' requires Python 3.8. I tried adding:

```
apt-get -y install python3
```

But it did not help. I also tried upgrading to the Go image 1.20.

Comment: What is the image you have used? You can check if it has been updated lately and maybe use a version previous to the update